# Should presentation layer be in control of business transactions?

Tags: transactions, presentation

Assuming having a typical Data Access layer, Business Layer and Presentation layer architecture.

Data Access layer has Repositories and a Unit of Work.

Business Layer has Data Service classes that consumes the Repositories.

Now assume that I have `Order` entity and `OrderItem` entity, business wise I could add an `Order` object to the database alone, or add an `Order` along with its `OrderItems`, or add a list `OrderItems` for an existing `Order`.

How do you think the Data Service API should look like?

**Solution 1:**

```
OrderDataService(UnitOfWork uow) // Constructor
OrderDataService.Add(Order order);
OrderItemDataService() // Constructor
OrderItemDataService.Add(OrderItem item);
```

Then use these two methods at the level of presentation to form all the possible variations of adding `Order` alone, `Order` with `OrderItems` etc. wrapping these operations in a Transaction (Unit of Work) at the Presentation layer level.

**Solution 2:**

```
OrderDataService() // Constructor
OrderDataService.Add(Order order);
OrderDataService.AddWithItems(Order order, List<OrderItem> items);
OrderItemDataService() // Constructor
OrderItemDataService.Add(List<OrderItem> items);
```

Then create the transaction (Unit of Work) inside these methods and let the Presentation layer be totally ignorant even of the simplest forms of transactions just by calling one method per transaction and let the business layer care for the rest?

Comment: What is `UnitOfWork`?

Comment: UnitOfWork is a pattern used to manager business transactions.

Comment: I do not think this question has one correct answer.